# React native ternary condition with AND logic

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a bunch of images in a view container and the images can be dragged and dropped. Initially all the images are clearly visible. When I drag a image other images should be in blur state. After I drop the image, again all images should be visible clearly.

The code is working for each condition separately:

[image]

But when I perform AND, all images are clearly visible where I need to blur unselected images:

[image]

This code is not working when state value change.

```
this.state.selectedItem != this.props.item && this.state.selectedItem !=null? new Animated.Value(0.2) : new Animated.Value(1)
```

Full code:

```
class Draggable extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      showDraggable: true,
      selectedItem: null,
      pan: new Animated.ValueXY()
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this._val = { x:0, y:0 }
    this.state.pan.addListener((value) => this._val = value);

    this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
        onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (e, gesture) => true,
        onPanResponderGrant: (e, gesture) => {
          this.state.pan.setOffset({
            x: this._val.x,
            y: this._val.y
          })
          this.state.pan.setValue({ x:0, y:0})
          this.setState({selectedItem: this.props.item})
        },
        onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
          null, { dx: this.state.pan.x, dy: this.state.pan.y }
        ]),
        onPanResponderRelease: (e, gesture) => {
          console.log("this.state.selectedItem = " + this.state.selectedItem);
          this.setState({selectedItem: null})
        },
      });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View pointerEvents="auto" style={{ width: "50%"}}>
        {this.renderDraggable()}
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderDraggable() {
    const {selectedItem} = this.state;
    const panStyle = {
      transform: this.state.pan.getTranslateTransform()
    }

    if (this.state.showDraggable) {
      return (
        <Animated.View key={this.props.keyProp}
          {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
          style={[panStyle, {opacity: this.state.selectedItem != this.props.item && this.state.selectedItem !=null? new Animated.Value(0.2) : new Animated.Value(1), position: 'absolute'}]}
        >
          <FastImage source={{uri: this.props.item}} style= {styles.itemsInSet}/>
        </Animated.View>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

The `Draggable` component is being called here:

```
<View style={styles.imageContainerView}>
  {this.state.items.map((item) => {
    return <Draggable key={item.id} keyProp={item.id} item={item.uri}/> 
  })}
</View>
```

Comment: So what do you want exactly? to change the style of all the rest of the images?

Comment: Yes. While dragging a image, I want to blur other images i.e change image opacity into 0.2.

Comment: @c-chavez I updated my code. Please see my edited post

Comment: First of all, use `componentDidMount` not `componentWillMount`, have a read [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount)

Comment: How do you know if the component is the selectedItem? are you calling this component from a different one and passing a prop? could you show us?

Comment: Yes. I am calling the component from another page like this <View style={styles.imageContainerView}>
          {this.state.items.map((item) => {
            return <Draggable key={item.id} keyProp={item.id} item={item.uri}/>
          })}
        </View>

Comment: @c-chavez Any input on this issue